# How to excute bin/setup of Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am with this file of cloned repo in Ruby:

[image]

Anyone knows how to execut the setup file?

I try "ruby bin/setup" but I get this: ruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)

Comment: It's obviously a bash script. Why are you going to run it with Ruby? You have to install one of the many bash implementations for Windows. I'm using Cygwin's, but recently, WSL (by Microsoft) and git-bash seem to be popular as well. There is also a good commercial implementation by MKS which contains a bash. The whole product is called the "MKS Toolkit".

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is actually a bash script and not a ruby script. If the permissions of the file are set to executable you can can just run `./setup` to execute the script in the working directory or `./bin/setup` from the root project directory.

Otherwise you will need to run `chmod +x filename` to update the file permissions so it is executable.

Comment: I did, but I am using Windows. I use Cmder, but even though doesn´t works. I need Linux?

Comment: you should probably set up bash for windows or the windows subsystem for linux see this for more info: https://superuser.com/questions/608106/how-can-i-use-a-bash-like-shell-on-windows

Comment: it would help to specify this in the question as well for the future as well as not use images.

Answer (score 0):

setup is a bash script, not a Ruby one. Just call it from the command line. e.g. `./bin/setup`